# htaccess rewrite rule to redirect domain to load from a folder without showing folder name in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, rule

I have the following rewrite rule for domain to load from a folder. The problem that I am having when I try to go to `http://www.mydomainfolder.com/somerfolder` then it redirect and shows "mydomainfolder" in the address (`http://www.mydomainfolder.com/mydomainfolder/somefolder/index.php`) but if add trailing slash (`http://www.mydomainfolder.com/somerfolder/`) then it doesn't show the mydomainfodler in the address. What I am doing wrong here. Please help!!

```
       Options +FollowSymLinks

       RewriteEngine On


       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)?smydomain.com$
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydomainfolder/
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mydomainfolder/$1
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)?mydomain.com$
       RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /mydomainfolder/$1/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your rules with:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /mydomainfolder/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydomainfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /mydomainfolder/$1/ [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but doesn't work... its the same thing

Comment: Is `somerfolder` a real directory inside `/mydomainfolder/`?

Comment: Yes, ./somefolder has index.php inside

Comment: No that is due to your browser caching. Test it in a new browser.

Comment: if you have time could you please explain what I was doing wrong.

Comment: It is the trailing slash in `/mydomainfolder/$1/ [L]` making all the difference. Your rule was rewriting to `/mydomainfolder/subdir` and that is a valid directory then `mod_dir` steps in and redirects that to `/mydomainfolder/subdir/`. With trailing slash already in `mod_dir` doesn't fire.